# Saving arrays on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array that contains widgets `List<ListCard> listsList= [];` And inside each widget I have an array that has objects of a class called Product `List<Product> products = [];`. Through the app you can add products to the list but I want to save this 2 arrays (and the inner objects). How can I do it? I thought I can do a database but maybe there is something more straightforward than designing all the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage . It is pretty straighforward

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to this:

1) Use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package, it's pretty simple to use and doesn't require you to write anything super complex. One downside - data is saved on the device, so if the app is deleted - all information is lost.

2) Attach Firebase Storage, using official packages. Installation of it is not complex at all, though you will need to convert your Product to Map

Both methods are valid and pretty fast to implement without groundbreaking changes.

If any questions occur - feel free to ask :3

Comment: Thank you so much! But I think that the first package can't save lists

Comment: Well, it kinda can - just create Map<String, dynamic> any = {"data": products}
It will work, though it's not the prettiest solution

Comment: So instead of saving a list, it would be saving n elements individually?